# Make Excel open .xls web hyperlinks in the browser

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When you create a hyperlink in Excel to a file on the web (say a file that is updated daily) and click on the link, instead of (what I would say is the expected behavior of "shell executing a resource") opening the link in the default browser (i.e. downloading it with chrome without overwriting previously downloaded files), Excel opens it directly.

When doing so, Excel:

1. Saves a copy of the file to a temp folder (not sure where)
2. You can't use Excel while it downloads and checks the file. If you're accessing a 13MB file on a slow connection, you're doomed.
3. References to that spreadsheets are like this: `='http://www.website.com/[file.xls]sheet'!$A$1`

Is there any way to disable this "feature"?

Comment: It has been suggested multiple times to change the default behavior of hyperlinks in Excel, but Microsoft has been quite silent regarding this. Good luck!

Comment: Ohhh, so I gather that there's nothing to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Excel (or indeed Windows) with which to check this right now, but I believe when I did I used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> to make links open in the browser.

Comment: You can't ctrl+click a link in Excel (the cursor changes to the discontinuous range selection mode).